# Copying files to their parent directory, prefixed with their directory name

Tags: powershell

In short, I have a list of dated directories, containing lists of files.

I need a list of files prefixed with date.

I can't make sure the input is more useful, because the dating on the directory changes as their status changes.

So far, I've dug up a method to rename files prefixed with their directory name.

```
gci "C:\Directory to find files" -recurse | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $false} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + " - " + $_.Name}
```

However, I'm a powershell newbie (literally five minutes ago) an my experience with batch files did not prepare me for this.  How can I get this to copy the files to a parent directory?

Comment: can you expand on your question with a sample dir name(s) and file(s) in them as an example of what you start with and follow that with the expected changes?  2 to 3 of each may suffice.

if you are new, sometimes not using many (or any) pipelines will let you debug easier in VSCode or ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Build the destination name from the components using the `-Format` operator

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Directory to find files" -Recurse -File |
    Copy-Item -Destination {"{0}\{1}-{2}" -f $_.Directory.Parent.Fullname,
                                             $_.Directory.Name,
                                             $_.Name } -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`